# UITableView in every UICollectionView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview, cell

I've been searching about getting a UITableView inside UICollectionView cells, but so far I have only found the exact oposite: CollectionViews inside TableView cells.
My approach is the following:

Collection View Controller:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cell

    }
}
```

Custom CollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tableView = UITableView()
        self.contentView.addSubview(tableView)
    }

}
```

The goal is to have information displayed in pages that scroll horizontally, and each page can have many rows (thus TableViews inside CollectionViews). 
However I can't seem to figure out how to have one TableViewController for every TableView instance added to the CollectionView's cells.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to add a datasource to the tableview and load it with data??

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, for instance, making the UiCollectionViewCell conform to UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: Yes.. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: No, I haven’t. Didn’t know that conforming to the protocol would solve my problem. Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll flag your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this really deserves an answer.. but circling back to our comment discussion...

You can conform UICollectionView to the tableview protocols just like any UIView or UIViewController.